# Upgrading OS Server after installing applications

Tags: windows-server-2008, upgrade

I have installed certain applications in my VM which has Windows OS Server 2008. Now, If I upgrade the Windows Server to 2012, will it affect my applications in anyway?

I could see that the application is supported in 2012 Server.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the applications, but most should be fine.  I would recommend taking a snapshot of your old installation so that you can quickly go back to WS 2008 if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Check with application vendor if they support 2012 version OS. Don't upgrade the instance without a snapshot. Most applications should work, unless any App-OS dependency.